# React native JSON and State

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and to programming in general. I need help here.

I have a simple login screen where user enters email and password. When user clicks on login button, I call my web service to check number of matching records in my DB for that email/password combination. web service returns count in JSON format. But I am getting blank for count. I am doubting this has to do with setting state.

JSON from web service:
    {"Subscriber":[{"count":"0"}]}

Here is my code:

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      uCount: '',
      data: []
    };
  }

  _onPressButton() {

    this.getData();

    console.log("email:", this.state.email);
    console.log("passwd:", this.state.password);

    console.log("data", this.state.data);
    console.log("uCount", this.state.uCount);

    if (this.state.uCount < 1) {
        Alert.alert('Fail')
    } else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginSuccess', { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password})      
    }
  }

 getData(){
    var url="myurl.php?email=" + this.state.email + "&password=" + this.state.password;
    console.log("URL:", url);
    return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
     this.setState({
      data: responseJson.Subscriber,
      uCount: responseJson.Subscriber[0].count
    })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

On button click I am calling _onPressButton function which call getData function to call web service and get count from JSON. I have verified url construction is correct and it returns correct JSON. when I print

```js
console.log("data", this.state.data);
console.log("uCount", this.state.uCount);
```

After calling getData function the data array is null and count is blank as initialized

```js
data []
uCount
```

This means below code is not working.

```js
.then((responseJson) => {
     this.setState({
      data: responseJson.Subscriber,
      uCount: responseJson.Subscriber[0].count
    })
```

Please help.

Comment: try `console.log(responseJson)`? what's inside of it

Comment: Object {Subscriber: Array(1)}
Subscriber
:
Array(1)
0
:
Object
count
:
"0"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: responseJson is showing correct object

Comment: Your `console.log` inside `_onPressButton()` didn't provide you correct information. You `setState` inside a `promise.then` which is a async response, but console.log it synchronously.

Comment: try it again with  `async _onPressButton() { await this.getData();` ?

Answer (score 0):

i have one solution, maybe can help you, first change your get data, using return promise, so we must wait for this function firts before `console.log`

```
getData(){
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    var url="myurl.php?email=" + this.state.email + "&password=" + this.state.password;
    console.log("URL:", url);
    return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        data: responseJson.Subscriber,
        uCount: responseJson.Subscriber[0].count
      })
      resolve(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
 })
}
```

and then you can change your `_onPressButton()` to this one :

```
_onPressButton() {

    this.getData()
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("email:", this.state.email);
        console.log("passwd:", this.state.password);

        console.log("data", this.state.data);
        console.log("uCount", this.state.uCount);

        if (this.state.uCount < 1) {
            Alert.alert('Fail')
        } else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginSuccess', { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password})      
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Hope it can help you, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks val and Rizal, both solutions return correct data but I have to press login twice. If I press login once then nothing happens. when press it second time then only fail message or redirects to second navigation page. any idea why?

Comment: Running application Stockcast2 ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
infoLog.js:17 Running application "Stockcast2" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF

Comment: After entering email and password when click login button nothing happens but if I click login button again then navigation page loads twice. I am not sure what's going on. I'll appreciate any help here.